# How to send a file and a number/string to a Servlet from html?

Tags: java, html, servlets

i got something like this in my html page:

```
<form method="post" action="UploadServlet"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" size="60" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="idPicture" value="{{selectedStudent.id}}">
    <br /> <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

and the 4th line is the problem...without that line, my code just uploads the file i selected...and all works...

and then, i just add that simple line to the code, and it returns

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT000018: Form value is a String, use getValue() instead
```

and in the servlet, there is nothing that consumes that parameter...

later i placed the following code in comments...

String idPicture = request.getParameter("idPicture").toString();

PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

out.println(idPicture);

and it is still in comments....i just added the new input field....
and i dont know what to do

here is the code:

```
@WebServlet("/UploadServlet")
@MultipartConfig
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //here was my code in comments i added above

    // gets absolute path of the web application
    String appPath = "C:/.../workspace/CreditCardWEB/WebContent/images/";
    // constructs path of the directory to save uploaded file
    String savePath = appPath + File.separator;

    // creates the save directory if it does not exists
    File fileSaveDir = new File(savePath);
    if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
        fileSaveDir.mkdir();
    }

    for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
        String fileName = extractFileName(part);
        part.write(savePath + File.separator + "studImg100.jpg");
                    //here is where the number is needed...
                    //i want to create a file with the number in its name

    }
}
```

Still, i dont know where the error is

I hope u can help me...

Comment: Try to clean and the build the code and stop/Start server as well

Comment: already tried that

Comment: the joke is, once i remove the 4th line, all works....once i add it...i get the error java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT000018: Form value is a String, use getValue() instead

Comment: please show us the whole all stack trace?

Comment: here we go....i posted it as an answer